# Parametrized Template Class constructor with another template class

Tags: c++, class, templates

I am trying to initialize a `Calculator` with two `Complex` variables. Both these classes are template classes.

calculator.h

```
#ifndef CALCULATOR_H
#define CALCULATOR_H

template <class U>
class Calculator{
    private:
        U left_val;
        U right_val;
    public:
        Calculator(){}
        Calculator(U m_left_val, U m_right_val){
            left_val = m_left_val;
            right_val = m_right_val;
        }
        U add();
        U subtract();
};

#endif
```

complex.h

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_H
#define COMPLEX_H

template <class T>
class Complex{
    private:
        T m_real;
        T m_imaginary;
    public:
        Complex(){}
        Complex(T real = 0 , T imaginary = 0){
            m_real = real;
            m_imaginary = imaginary;
        }
        Complex operator + (const Complex& complex);
        Complex operator - (const Complex& complex);
};

#endif
```

In my main:

```
Calculator<double> floatCalc(30.3, 20.7);
Calculator<int> intCalc(100, 30);
Complex<double> a(2.0, 4.0);
Complex<double> b(1.0, 2.0);
Calculator<Complex<double>> complexCalc(a, b); //This is the line in question
```

I am getting two compile time errors that only relate to the initialization of `complexCalc` and they are the same error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:3:
calculator.h: In instantiation of 'Calculator<U>::Calculator() [with U = Complex<double>]':
main.cpp:11:33:   required from here
calculator.h:10:21: error: call of overloaded 'Complex()' is ambiguous
   10 |         Calculator(){}
      |                     ^
In file included from main.cpp:2:
complex.h:11:9: note: candidate: 'Complex<T>::Complex(T, T) [with T = double]'
   11 |         Complex(T real = 0 , T imaginary = 0){
      |         ^~~~~~~
complex.h:10:9: note: candidate: 'Complex<T>::Complex() [with T = double]'
   10 |         Complex(){}
      |         ^~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:3:
calculator.h:10:21: error: call of overloaded 'Complex()' is ambiguous
   10 |         Calculator(){}
      |                     ^
In file included from main.cpp:2:
complex.h:11:9: note: candidate: 'Complex<T>::Complex(T, T) [with T = double]'
   11 |         Complex(T real = 0 , T imaginary = 0){
      |         ^~~~~~~
complex.h:10:9: note: candidate: 'Complex<T>::Complex() [with T = double]'
   10 |         Complex(){}
      |         ^~~~~~~
```

I don't know what this means or how to fix it.

Comment: Note you would see the same problem without involving `Calculator` with just `Complex<double> x;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that there's no way to differentiate between the zero parameter constructor of `Calculator`, and the two parameter constructor with default arguments. You should just remove your zero parameter constructor.